# How do I start the process of debugging raw php code from a Wordpress site after an update?

Tags: php, wordpress, express, debugging, mamp

I need to debug some errors and formatting within a professional wordpress site. I need to do the debugging from the raw code. It is mostly php and JS. I have ended up with more than 2million lines of code after the most recent update. There are some empty box space on the home page and a list of bugs from the WP_DEBUG log.

This is my first time working with Wordpress at all. I am overwhelmed by the amount of code, and can't figure out where any of the bugs and issues are. I have worked with Angular Typescript in the past.

I would assume, to an extent, that some of these issues would be able to be fixed within the 'drag and drop' API of wordpress, but I have no idea how to use that either, when there is an already several million lined website code, and like I said, I was given the raw php code of over 2 mil lines to debug with.

I have been using VS code for the editor and MAMP as a live server.

I have no idea where to start, and I have not been able to find any useful tutorials online. Any help is greatly appreciated. I could really just use some guidance on how this process might work. Or if it even is something that people do, ever. It looks like according to the internet, this may not be the way to go about debugging. Feel free to ask questions I'll try to answer anything I can without giving away any confidential info.

Here are the bugs that show up on the site from WP_Debug:

```
Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '*' found in C:\repos\website\wp-content\mu-plugins\no-cache.php on line 8
Warning: preg_match(): Empty regular expression in C:\repos\website\wp-content\mu-plugins\no-cache.php on line 8
Notice: Trying to get property 'Location' of non-object in C:\repos\website\wp-content\themes\Child-Theme\functions.php on line 45
Notice: Trying to get property 'Subrole' of non-object in C:\repos\website\wp-content\themes\Child-Theme\functions.php on line 46
```

Update: I am still having issues with these same errors. I am looking for assistance on how the process of debugging raw WP php code works, and if I am trying the right things. I can provide the code that a few errors are pointing to, but I do have to adjust the variables to maintain confidentiality.

\Child-Theme\functions.php (35-50):

```
if(class_exists(\RoleList\RoleList::class)) {
  wp_localize_script('site-name', 'SiteName', [
    'RoleList' => [
      'categories' => $role_categories,
      'locations' => \RoleList\Categories::getLocations(),
      'category_counts' => \RoleList\Listings::getCategoryCounts(),
    ],
    'CurrentRole' => [
      'is_role_page' => ($listing ? true : false),
      'current_category' => ($current_category ? $current_category : null),
      'current_location' => ($listing->Location ? $listing->Location : null),
      'current_subrole' => ($listing->Subrole ? $listing->Subrole : null),
      'home_url' => home_url(),
    ]
  ]);
}
```

Comment: As you haven't shared any of the bugs you are facing, it's impossible to provide help. But something like XDebug or vardump can be a good start

Comment: The errors from the log should alert you to the file name & line number where they occurred, so you should be able to close in on where you need to look. As for stuff in the frontend that doesn't look like it's supposed to, try & identify what part of the functionality they actually are part of first. Check what the content editor contains in those places, try and figure out whether it is core functionality, or comes from a specific plugin.

Comment: I'll see if there are any bugs I can share immediately. Thank you I will look into XDebug and vardump.

Comment: I have edited original question, and added some gently modified error logs to show the WP_DEBUG that shows up on the webpage.

Comment: Please also share the code involved. Nobody can guess from the error log **why** these lines are broken. Finally, also share your attempts to resolve the problem. Maybe the plugins you are using are not compatible with the PHP or Wordpress version you are using? Maybe the plugins are not configured properly?

Comment: I have edited to add the actual code for some of the errors. I am still very stuck on these issues. How does one navigate WP code of several million lines to debug an update? I need more help just determining what my next steps are, rather than a direct-fix for these errors. Any Feedback is greatly appreciated.